# What is the minimum value of a 32-bit signed integer?

Tags: int, 32-bit, signed, minimum

What is the minimum value of a 32-bit signed integer, happens to be the security "challenge" question in order to make an account at [this website](edit: link is now malware) (don't judge I'm just curious and bored).

I assumed they were talking about a typical 32bit int which can store numbers as big as `2,147,483,647`.  But when I tried `-2147483647` it said I got the question wrong.  I tried several variations such as `-2,147,483,647` but nothing works...

Am I misinterpreting the question or is there something wrong with the web site?

PS I also tried -2,147,483,648 as suggested

Here's a picture
[image]

Comment: Have you tried -2147483648, or possibly even 0

Comment: Did you read the question carefully before entering the number? I noticed it bounces between asking for the maximum and asking for the minimum (hit refresh a few times and watch it change). Make sure you know which one! ;)

Answer (score 41):

The most used size of an integer is 32 bits. The last bit is used to distinguish positive and negative numbers. If the last bit is NOT set, then the number is positive. Therefore, the maximal positive number is `0x7FFFFFFF` = `(1<<31)-1`=`2147483647` (the last bit is not set).

For the negative numbers, two's complement notation is widely used. You can identify the counterpart of the positive number by inverting its all bits and adding 1. Thus, the counterpart for the maximal integer is `0x80000001`, however it is **NOT** the minimal number.

The minimal number in two's complement notation is `0x80000000` = `-2147483648`.
The interesting fact about this number is that it is equal to its own complement, i.e. inverting all bits results in `0x7FFFFFFF` and adding 1 yields `0x80000000`, which is equal to the original number.

More about two's complement notation in [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement).

Answer (score 9):

Signed 32 bit integers can go down to `-2,147,483,648`

Comment: Incidentally, when I go to that site, it asks me for the maximum? Is it possible that you read it wrong/it asks a different question each time?

Comment: I noticed that it changes every few refreshes.

Comment: I added a picture to answer your questions

Comment: there must be something wrong with the form, it accepts the correct maximum, and I double checked in Java (incase it was something silly like formatting) and this line: `System.out.printf("%d", Integer.MIN_VALUE)` gives: `-2147483648`

Comment: I got it to accept the max value... weird that it didn't work with the min.

Comment: email them and tell them the form is broken - I tried, but you have to create an account and login - too much like hard work for me!